# Excel VBA programming - Making a simple world cup excel program

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing some vba programming in excel, i havnt programmed much and sorta new to this. But over to my question.

Quick question. I want to have a stack of cells made in to a group. So if one cells increases in value and for instance move up because of sorting, then i want the other cells connected to this cell moving with it.

**Check this picture:**

[image]

If for instance Brazil gets a value increase in one of the cells to its right, then that row will bump over the Mexico row.

So how can i make a group of cells stick together?

Comment: What would be the logic to move Brazil above Mexico e.g. if first cell to the right for Brazil increases by 1 but is less than the corresponding cell for Mexico should it move the row up? What are your column headers?

Comment: Yes. You can add another column which adds up the rest of the columns with number then sort by that column. You can do this in VBA as well.

Comment: I agree with L42, I would say have a column (hidden if you need it to be) that sums up the total numbers in the row and use a `Worksheet_OnChange` event that sorts by that column.

Answer (score 0):

To explain my answer a bit, consider this layout in Sheet1:

```
            Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4    Column 5    Total
USA         15          0           0           0           0           15
Mexico      8           2           0           0           0           10
Germany     0           0           0           6           0           6
Brazil      2           0           0           0           0           2
Argentina   0           0           0           0           0           0
```

And this code in Sheet1 of your workbook

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G1", Me.Range("G" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).DirectPrecedents) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1", Me.Range("G" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Sort key1:=Me.Range("G1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End If

End Sub
```

Now, whenever you change any of the numbers in columns 1 - 5, when the total if column G (Total) is updated, it will sort the entire range on that column.

Answer (score 0):

"So how can i make a group of cells stick together?"
Sorts are done by rows, so you get what you want.
I would use a named range (say, "name1").
Assuming you have a 9th column for the total that you want to sort on,

```
Range("name1").Select ' not needed
With Range("name1")
  .Sort Key1:=.Columns(9), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

'(From Dave Peterson https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/microsoft.public.excel.programming/sort$20%22named$20range%22$20column$20key/microsoft.public.excel.programming/WyO1WRdBtSI/CUeHU1Q9TfsJ)